# C fwrite function giving data with unknow space

Tags: c

This function is supposed to get a parameter as the pointer of a file and put all file into the `struct anagram`, then write it to another file. Right now the each data has a lot of space bewteen them. The charCompare is working fine since i make a test file to test it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "anagrams.h"
#define SIZE 80

//struct
struct anagram {
char word[SIZE];
char sorted[SIZE];
};

void buildDB ( const char *const dbFilename ){

    FILE *dict, *anagramsFile;
    struct anagram a;

    //check if dict and anagram.data are open
    errno=0;
    dict= fopen(dbFilename, "r");

    if(errno!=0) {
        perror(dbFilename);
        exit(1);
    }

    errno=0;

    anagramsFile = fopen(anagramDB,"wb");

    char word[SIZE];
    char *pos;
    int i=0;

    while(fgets(word, SIZE, dict) !=NULL){

        //get ripe of the '\n'
        pos=strchr(word, '\n');
        *pos = '\0';

        //lowercase word
        int j=0;
        while (word[j]){
            tolower(word[j]);
            j++;
        }

        /* sort array using qsort functions */ 
        qsort(word,strlen(word), sizeof(char), charCompare);

        strncpy(a.sorted,word,sizeof(word));

        fwrite(&a,1,sizeof(struct word),anagramsFile);

        i++;
    }
    fclose(dict);
    fclose(anagramsFile);

}
```

data:
     10th                       1st                      2nd

Comment: Have you looked at the maximum line length of `dict` and the value of `BUFSIZ` ?

Comment: are you sure the segfault is at that line?

Comment: I see you're using strncpy(), which is very rarely the right function. See my article ['No, strncpy() is not a "safer" strcpy()](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html)

Comment: Can you post the `charCompare` function?

Answer (score 3):

A probable cause is the size argument passed to [`qsort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). From the linked reference page for `qsort()`:

> **size** - size of each element in the array in bytes

Therefore the size argument should be `1`, which is guaranteed to be `sizeof(char)`, and not `sizeof(char*)` which is likely to be `4` or `8`. The posted code incorrectly informs `qsort()` that `word` is pointing to an array of `4` (or `8`) times larger than the actual array and `qsort()` will access memory it is not supposed to. Change to:

```
qsort(word,strlen(word), 1, charCompare);
```

Another possible cause is buffer overrun caused by this line:

```
strncpy(&a.sorted[i],word,sizeof(word));
```

`i` is being incremented on every iteration of the `while` loop but `sizeof(word)` is always being written. The values of `SIZE` and `BUFSIZ` are not posted but even if they were equal the `strncpy()` will write beyond the bounds of `a.sorted` after the first iteration.

Other points:

- [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) is not guaranteed to read the new-line character so check return value of `strchr()` before dereferencing it.
- [`tolower()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) returns the lowercase character, it does not change its argument.
- why read into a temporary buffer (`word`) and copy? Just read directly into the `struct` members.

Comment: it still giving me segmentation fault

Comment: i run gdb on it, it stop at fgets()

Comment: @keivn, try checking that `dict != NULL` instead of querying `errno`.

Comment: strncpy(a.sorted,word,sizeof(word));

Comment: i change it to that, it still giving me segmenatation fault

Comment: cuz i think im passing anagram.sorted should be fine